# Mapping row according to column value

Tags: python, r, merge

This task could have been easily done in R/Python using `merge`, if log file was in csv.

But log file is written in following syntax

```
Key=1|Time=146656456446
Key=2|Time=146656456447
Key=1|Time=146656456448|field=10
Key=2|Time=146656456450|field=11
```

What could be a way to merge it and get the diff in the following way to

```
Key,Time1,Time2,diff,field
Key=1,146656456446,146656456448,2,10
Key=2,146656456447,146656456450,3,11
```

Comment: Could you be more precise? 
Do you know the number of possible Key values?
If the task is easy in R or Python what prevent you to use them?

Comment: Key values are used to map to the corresponding timestamp (there will always be a pair,key values will be ints). Task was easy if the format used column headers (like in csv) I could have used merge by Key column. Hope I'm clear

Comment: @pythonRcpp, read the data in, `gsub` out the "Key=" and "Time=", reshape the data to a "wide" format, and add a column for the difference.

Comment: Also, your "diff" seems wrong.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 corrected :)

Comment: Which language do you need this in? And what have you tried that did not work?

Comment: python or R. I tried converting log to a csv format and then use merge command in R. But there should be a better way

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment into an answer, here's an approach using the "data.table" package.

```
library(data.table)
x <- "path/to/yourLogFile.txt"      
mydt <- fread(x, header = FALSE, col.names = c("Key", "Time"))

dcast(mydt[, Time := as.numeric(sub("Time=", "", Time))][
  , Ind := sequence(.N), Key], Key ~ Ind, value.var = "Time")[
    , Diff := `2` - `1`][]
#      Key            1            2 Diff
# 1: Key=1 146656456446 146656456448    2
# 2: Key=2 146656456447 146656456450    3
```

Another similar approach using my "splitstackshape" package and the same steps to read in the data could look like:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(getanID(cSplit(mydt, "Time", "="), "Key"), 
      Key ~ Time_1 + .id, value.var = "Time_2")[
        , Diff := Time_2 - Time_1, by = Key][]
#      Key       Time_1       Time_2 Diff
# 1: Key=1 146656456446 146656456448    2
# 2: Key=2 146656456447 146656456450    3
```

For reading the log file, I made the following assumptions:

- You know there are two columns expected.
- Your log file doesn't currently have column names (hence the `header = FALSE`).
- You expect the data to be separated by the `|` character, which `fread` would be able to automatically detect.

---

### Update

It ain't pretty, but it works....

```
dcast(getanID(cSplit(mydt, names(mydt), "="), "Key_2"), 
      Key_2 ~ .id, fun=list(I, I), value.var = list("Field_2", "Time_2"), fill = 0)[
        , c("Field_2_I_1", "Diff") := list(NULL, Time_2_I_2 - Time_2_I_1)][]
##    Key_2 Field_2_I_2   Time_2_I_1   Time_2_I_2 Diff
## 1:     1          10 146656456446 146656456448    2
## 2:     2          11 146656456447 146656456450    3
```

#### Sample data

```
## Just to simulate a log file like the one you describe....
## "temp" would be your actual file....
x <- c("Key=1|Time=146656456446", "Key=2|Time=146656456447", 
       "Key=1|Time=146656456448|field=10", "Key=2|Time=146656456450|field=11")
temp <- tempfile() 
writeLines(x, temp)

mydt <- fread(temp, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, 
              col.names = c("Key", "Time", "Field"))
mydt
##      Key              Time    Field
## 1: Key=1 Time=146656456446         
## 2: Key=2 Time=146656456447         
## 3: Key=1 Time=146656456448 field=10
## 4: Key=2 Time=146656456450 field=11
```

Comment: Haven't seen you for long time..  Glad that you are back!

Comment: @akrun, thanks. Not sure how "back" I am though :-) Too much going on at work these days!

Comment: This mostly works for me, Just that in each pair 1 row has 1 column extra. Is there any way to include that into the merged row? eg. `row1 Key=1|Time=123 row2 Key=1|Time=125|extraColumnVal=99 mergedRow2: 1,123,125,2,99`

Comment: Have updated my question, seems like I forgot to add 1 extra column value in the question

Comment: @pythonRcpp, Why don't you share a few more lines of sample data so there's no ambiguity about what you're working with and what output you want to get. For instance, does the extra column only appear for the second instance of a key?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 yes extra column would appear "only" in 2nd instance.

Comment: I also converted the log into csv using bash, but have a problem aggregating the result, could you also check my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642091/aggregate-in-r-ignoring-certain-columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the time in columns, the following will work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- read_table(
"test       
Key=1|Time=146656456446  
Key=2|Time=146656456447  
Key=1|Time=146656456448  
Key=2|Time=146656456450" )
```

Separate the string by "|" then by "=" to get the number

```
df <-
df %>% 
  separate(test, into = c("Key", "Time"), sep = "\\|") %>% 
  separate(Time, into = c("Timepoint", "Time"), sep = "=")

df
# A tibble: 4 × 3
    Key Timepoint         Time
* <chr>     <chr>        <chr>
1 Key=1      Time 146656456446
2 Key=2      Time 146656456447
3 Key=1      Time 146656456448
4 Key=2      Time 146656456450
```

Change time to numeric and group by Key to calculate difference

```
df$Time <- as.numeric(df$Time)

df <-
df %>% 
  group_by(Key) %>% 
  summarise(Diff = diff(Time))

df
# A tibble: 2 × 2
    Key  Diff
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Key=1     2
2 Key=2     3
```