# Aggregate adjacent rows, ignoring certain columns

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I have a df like below

```
> head(df)
  OrderId           Timestamp ErrorCode
1 3000000 1455594300434609920        NA
2 3000001 1455594300434614272        NA
3 3000000 1455594300440175104         0
4 3000001 1455594300440179712         0
5 3000002 1455594303468741120        NA
6 3000002 1455594303469326848         0
```

I need to collapse row in a way that output is something like below

```
> head(df)
  OrderId         Timestamp1  Timestamp2       ErrorCode Diff
 3000000 1455594300434609920  1455594300440175104      0
 3000001 1455594300434614272  1455594300440179712      0
 3000002 1455594303468741120  1455594303469326848      0
```

I used `df2=aggregate(Timestamp~.,df,FUN=toString)`
But output is

```
   OrderId ErrorCode           Timestamp
10 3000001         0 1455594300440179712
11 3000002         0 1455594303469326848
12 3000003         0 1455594303713897984
```

When I dropped the ErrorCode column and used the same command, I get an expected output

```
> head(kf)
  OrderId           Timestamp
1 3000000 1455594300434609920
2 3000001 1455594300434614272
3 3000000 1455594300440175104
4 3000001 1455594300440179712
5 3000002 1455594303468741120
6 3000002 1455594303469326848
> kf2=aggregate(Timestamp~.,kf,FUN=toString)
head(kf2)
   OrderId                                Timestamp
10 3000001 1455594300434614272, 1455594300440179712
11 3000002 1455594303468741120, 1455594303469326848
12 3000003 1455594303711330816, 1455594303713897984
```

How do I aggregate it in the above manner without removing ErrorCode column. There must be some little thing I am missing.

Comment: what function do you apply on `ErrorCode`?

Comment: Merge to itself then filter? `res <- merge(df1, df1, by = "OrderId"); res <- res[ res$Timestamp.x != res$Timestamp.y, ]`

Comment: Errocode just needs to be merged according to OrderId, NA and 0 merge to 0.

Comment: Is there any case where `ErrorCode` would be other than zero?

Comment: yes it can be any value but either NA or some number (in a pair). There will be a key value pair for every orderId, once they are matched, they just need to merged (int and NA as errocode)

Comment: So, If you were to use `dplyr`, is that what you want? `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(OrderId) %>% summarise(Timestamp = toString(Timestamp), ErrorCode = unique(ErrorCode[!is.na(ErrorCode)]))`

Comment: That's not aggregation, that's just combining adjacent rows (or equivalently, reshaping and renaming). Aggregate would be combining rows by some grouping variable, which you're not doing. (Unless you call using `row_index %/% 2` as the grouping variable)

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're actually looking just to reshape your data into a wide format with separate columns for timestamp 1 and 2. One way is to first add a new column that defines the time point of the measurement and then melt and cast the data using `reshape2`.

```
# Add an index to the data.frame
for (i in unique(df$OrderId)) {
  ii <- df$OrderId == i
  df$time_ind[ii] <- seq_along(ii[ii])
}

library(reshape2)

df_long <- melt(df, id.vars = c("OrderId", "time_ind"),
                measure.vars = c("Timestamp", "ErrorCode"))

dcast(df_long, OrderId ~ variable + time_ind)
```

which will give you

```
  OrderId         Timestamp_1         Timestamp_2 ErrorCode_1 ErrorCode_2
1 3000000 1455594300434609920 1455594300440175104        <NA>           0
2 3000001 1455594300434614272 1455594300440179712        <NA>           0
3 3000002 1455594303468741120 1455594303469326848        <NA>           0
```

Comment: yes you are correct in understanding what I need. Could you elaborate what `df$time_ind[ii] <- seq_along(ii[ii])` did how df_long is created. Why aggregate is unable to perform this. Thanks

Comment: As it stood, your data.frame had no variable to identify which timestamps were which but `dcast` needs that to unstack the columns. The code just indexes each successive appearance of a value of `OrderId` successively to provide this. I believe that `aggregate` doesn't know how to handle several value columns and is not really geared directly towards reshaping.